# Launch google-chrome from terminal with post request parameters

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, terminal

I know how to launch google-chrome from terminal with a specific url.

```
google-chrome http://klavogonki.ru/create/
```

Url that I launch that way has a plenty of form inputs that I must to fill. Ideally I want to launch google-chrome from terminal and get all form inputs already filled with predefined parameters and automatically submit form. 
I wondering is there any way to do it, maybe some flags for a google-chrome?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes  `google-chrome "http://example.com"`

or in the new window `google-chrome --new-window="http://example.com"`

or as an app `google-chrome --app="http://example.com"`